# spring security,web.ignoring() without effect

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-java-config

I just want to filter static resource:/**/*.js.
so, I add the follow configure

```
web.ignoring().mvcMatchers("/**/*.js")
```

**but the AntPathRequestMatcher Still called.**

the log like this:

```
[org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] - /static/jquery.1.12.4.min.js has an empty filter list
[org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : '/static/jquery.1.12.4.min.js'; against '/login'
[org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : '/static/jquery.1.12.4.min.js'; against '/test/select.action'
[org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : '/static/jquery.1.12.4.min.js'; against '/test/del.action'
[org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : '/static/jquery.1.12.4.min.js'; against '/test/add.action'
[org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : '/static/jquery.1.12.4.min.js'; against '/loginPage'
[org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] - Request '/static/jquery.1.12.4.min.js' matched by universal pattern '/**'
```

So the URL will be prevent,please help me !

thanks~~

Comment: Do you want that .js files can be accessed by unauthenticated users?

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the mvcMatchers above the antMatchers line.